# How to update Fmx.TPopupCell items in run time

Tags: delphi, grid, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am using a fireMonkey grid with one TPopupColumn. the items of this column are determined and also are changing during run time.

the problem is that the changes in the TpopupColumn.items are only reflected on the newly added rows in the popup column and the old ones have the old items (not Changed).

```
setlength(PointNames,NoMeasPoints);
setlength(PlaneNames,NoMeasPlanes);
PopupColumn1.Items.Clear;
Grid1.RowCount:=NoMeasPoints;
for i:=0 to NoMeasPlanes-1 do
begin
  PlaneNames[i]:= 'Plane '+inttostr(i+1);
  PopupColumn1.Items.Add(PlaneNames[i].ToString);
  Grid1.Repaint;
end;
```

if for example PopupColumn1 started with one cell with one item in its dropdown list and later another cell (row) was added with also change in items to be two. the 2nd cell displays the two items when clicked but the first cell only display the one item it had from the beginning.

is there any way to update the cell during run time.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: this delphi. I am using delphi xe5

Comment: You'll want to go over each cell in the column and update the items for each. It's not easy getting to the cells though. Maybe use Column[n].Children? I'll give a proper answer later if this isn't enough to get you going.

Comment: @MikeSutton, i tried to do exactly what you mentioned but Column[n].Children doesn't contain Items property to change the popupCell.Items. i did try to delete all popupcolumn then create them again. using that way i managed to access and update the PopupCell.Items. however i am facing now another problem when i try to change gid.RowCount i get memory access violation error

Comment: Any thoughts about how to update the PopupCell.Items during run time without deleting them first then creating them again. Deleting and creating cell does work put cause memory violation problems and display issues (e.g. cells is not highlighted when clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it for me:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Cell: TFMXObject;
begin
  if not (Grid1.Columns[0] is TPopupColumn) then
    EXIT;

  TPopupColumn(Grid1.Columns[0]).Items.Add('New Item');
  for Cell in Grid1.Columns[0].Children do
    if Cell is TPopupCell then
      TPopupCell(Cell).Items.Assign(TPopupColumn(Grid1.Columns[0]).Items);
end;
```

Just use the appropriate column index or your grid.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to Solve the problem by using the following code,

```
Procedure UpdateStringGrid1;
 Var i,j:integer;
 var item1:TPopupCell;
 Begin
  with MultiBalForm do
   begin
     Grid1.RowCount:=NoMeasPoints;
     setlength(PointNames,NoMeasPoints);
     setlength(PlaneNames,NoMeasPlanes);
     PopupColumn1.Items.Clear;
     popupcolumn1.DeleteChildren;
     for J := 0 to NoMeasPoints-1 do
     begin
       item1:=TPopupCell.Create(popupcolumn1);
       item1.Align:=TalignLayout.alTop;
       item1.Height:=25;
       for i:=0 to NoMeasPlanes-1 do
       begin
         PlaneNames[i]:='Plane ' + inttoStr(i+1);
         item1.Items.Add(PlaneNames[i].ToString);
       end;
       PopupColumn1.AddObject(item1);
     end;
  end;
end;
```

I call this procedure every time i want to update the popcolumn.items in which the cells are deleted by using "**DeleteChildren**" and then creating new popupcells with their updated items.

this may be not the best way.

Comment: Note: when calling this procedure a few times there is an error "memory access violation" when trying to change PopupColumn1.RowCount